# Windows impersonation token expiration time

Tags: windows, winapi, impersonation

Does anyone knows what is the expiration time for windows tokens created by LogonUser windows API method?

I was about to test it myself by polling whether the token changed each 10 minutes, but maybe it would be easier to ask what is the expiration time and where I can find the documentation that describes this.

What would be the default expiration time for the impersonation tokens? Can that be configured somewhere in the Active Directory?

Thanks,
AD

Comment: Any hint on that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expiration time of a standard logon token is infinite (0) because it is currently not supported.
See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> ExpirationTime
>
> Specifies the time at which this token expires. Expiration times for access tokens are not currently supported.